# Pandas get unique values in every column

Tags: pandas

I'd like to print unique values in each column of a grouped dataframe and the following code snippet doesn't work as expected:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1, 2, 1, 2], 'b' : [5, 5, 5, 5], 'c' : [11, 12, 13, 14]})
print(
  df.groupby(['a']).apply(
    lambda df: df.apply(
      lambda col: col.unique(), axis=0))
)
```

I'd expect it to print

```
1 [5] [11, 13]
2 [5] [12, 14]
```

While there are other ways of doing so, I'd like to understand what's wrong with this approach. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
print(df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].unique())

a | b |
--+---+---------
1 | 5 | [11, 13]
2 | 5 | [12, 14]
```

As to what's wrong with your approach - when you `groupby` on `df` and then `apply` some function `f`, the input for `f` will be a DataFrame with all of `df`'s columns, unless otherwise specified (as is in my code snippet with `['c']`). So your first `apply` is passing a DataFrame with 3 columns, and so is your second `apply`. Then your function `also_print` iterates over each of those 3 columns and prints them out, so you get 3 prints for every group.

Comment: this doesn't do what I want unfortunately, I'd like to group by 'a' only, and then in each of the groups get unique values in every column, like in the expected output I gave above.

Comment: also, forget about the also_print function, i removed it from the question since its not related. the question is about the final dataframe.

Comment: how about this?

`df.groupby('a').apply(lambda df: pd.Series([df[col].unique() for col in df.columns[1:]], index=df.columns[1:]))`

Comment: thanks, but as I said I'd like to understand what's wrong with my approach. what you suggest is a little more verbose.